# How to offline check SSL certificate chain?

Tags: validation, ssl, amazon-web-services, certificate

**Prologue**

I am periodically uploading & updating SSL certificates for AWS' elastic load balancers.

The annoying point is, that I submit certificate, private key and certificate chain and configure the load balancer but the interface is not validating the certificate on-the-fly. So when I actually press "CREATE LOAD BALANCER" I receive error messages regarding missing intermediate certificates or similar. I am not able to go back and correct the configuration. I have to start the whole process again. Not cool. ;)

**Question**

So what I am looking for is an offline- or online-service where I can post my certificat-chain that will then tell me that its the complete chain. Or not. There are some websites like sslshopper.com who offer some nice services to check existing websites, but I dont know any tool where I can just post the certificate-chain as plain text.

any help appreciated,
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer comes years after the OP asked the question.

I have found [Certificate Checker](https://tools.keycdn.com/ssl) while looking how to check certificate chain offline. The certificates must be in pem format. Enter the first certificate followed by the intermediate, then click Check. The tool will inform you if there is an issue detected with the chain or not, and also decode the certificate(s).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution / workaround for myself:

1. Create the AWS EC2 load balancer without the HTTPS-listener - you don't need to upload a certificate then
2. Edit the just created listener and try to add your certificate (private key, certificate, intermediate certificate)
3. If any error occurs, you easily can go back (the "back"-button is missing in the original load-balancer-creation-dialogue) and edit the certification information